# mac sierra php7 getting following error when run command apachectl -t

Tags: apache, php-7, macos-sierra

I have recently updated to Sierra, I am able to install php7, can see the version on Terminal. But getting following error when run command apachectl -t

httpd: Syntax error on line 170 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, 10): image not found

Appreciate your help

Comment: How did you install PHP7?

Comment: using homebrew,

Comment: do this lib get installed by default or anything special required. as i don't see this file under the specified path

Answer (score 2):

Your apache references the wrong path to the PHP module.

On my machine, using homebrew, the PHP5 module is installed here

```
LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.4/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

I am sure, the hombrew installed PHP 7 follows a similar pattern

Answer (score 0):

I have searched using Find command and found the module at
/usr/local/php5-7.0.11-20160923-203451/libphp7.so

Thanks